# Get graph execution error for BiLSTM and LSTM on keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow, lstm

I want to use BiLSTM mode for text classification tasks. I use a data generator to get already batched and embedded files that have been split into 64 different files(for training) and 4 files each for test and validation. The shape of the numpy.array is (512,768). I have used this method in the CNN model, which has higher parameters than this model for classification before, and it works fine.
However, when I try to use it in the BiLTSM model below

```
BiLSTM_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name = "BiLSTM_model")
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(300), input_shape = (512,768)))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
BiLSTM_model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
BiLSTM_model.summary()
```

I get this error immediately and do not start the epoch.  When I try on this fit

```
history = BiLSTM_model.fit(train_data_gen, 
                        steps_per_epoch = 64, 
                        epochs = 20, 
                        validation_data = valid_data_gen,
                        validation_steps=4,
                        verbose = 1)
```

```
InternalError: Graph execution error:

Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 768, 300, 1, 512, 1840, 300] 
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[BiLSTM_model/bidirectional/backward_lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5912]
```

I thought the model was too large for my GPU/RAM, so I tried testing it on a smaller LSTM model and tried it again with only one train and valid files.
model

```
BiLSTM_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(name = "BiLSTM_model")
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.LSTM(128, input_shape = (512,768)))
BiLSTM_model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
BiLSTM_model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])
BiLSTM_model.summary()
```

it is able to run to the end of first epoch but still crashes and stops working with this error

```
InternalError: Graph execution error:

Epoch 1/20
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6879 - accuracy: 0.9179
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 history = BiLSTM_model.fit(train_data_gen, 
      2                         steps_per_epoch = 1, 
      3                         epochs = 20, 
      4                         validation_data = valid_data_gen,
      5                         validation_steps=1,
      6                         verbose = 1)
      7 CNN_model.save("./finish_model/w2v_BiLSTM_model.h5")
      8 with open("./history/w2v_BiLSTM_history.pkl", "wb") as file_pi:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

InternalError: Graph execution error:

Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 768, 128, 1, 512, 3666, 128] 
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[BiLSTM_model/lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_test_function_3644]
```

I use Windows 10 OS with Nvidia GeForce RTX 3090 and Cuda 12.2. Tensorflow v2.10.1 and Keras v2.10.0 in Python 3.9.17 in Jupyter Notebook.

any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance.